# permission error reading python lambda code _sometimes_, I suspect because of conflicts with update-function-code

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an aws lambda in python 3.9 with a build number in it that I'm regularly updating from ci with the following code:

```sh
zip zip -g lambda_function.zip lambda_function.py
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name ... --zip-file lambda_function.zip
```

This never errors or anything, and *seems* to work.  However >50% of the time, when I try to call the lambda immediately afterwards - I just get "Internal server error"... and if I look at what's gone wrong in the back, I see:

```json
  "errorMessage": "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/task/lambda_function.py'",
  "errorType": "PermissionError",
  "requestId": "",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py\", line 127, in import_module\n    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1030, in _gcd_import\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1007, in _find_and_load\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 680, in _load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 846, in exec_module\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 982, in get_code\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 1039, in get_data\n"
  ]
}
```

Then, after a certain amount of time it seems to start working again *but with the last working version* - the version I tried to promote just seemed to vanish into thin air.   the weird thing, is, some of the time it works.   I googled that error and found people talking about permissions of the file inside the zip - so added this code:

```sh
chmod 644 $(find . -type f)
chmod 755 $(find . -type d)
```

before zipping.   Which achieved absolutely nothing.

It really feels like a race condition of some sort on the update... something like use of  the lambda while trying to update it breaks it or something like that - but I don't know what to do next or how to fix it.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've came across the same issue and fixed somewhat drastically by changing permission of the application and requirements packages.
**/home/app** contains my lambda modules and **requirements.txt**.
Inside that directory I've run:

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt -t .
```

after I've run:

```
RUN chmod -R 755 /home/app
```

and it worked.
The one you applied to the zip seems the refined version and for what I've experienced I would try to apply it to requirements packages.